# For what values of K will the monopolist choose to make and sell only high quality cars?

Tags: microeconomics

A monopoly auto manufacturer produces cars and can choose the quality
of the car produced. Let x be a measure of quality, and assume that the marginal cost of
a unit of quality is constant and equal to 1. There are two types of consumers that are
potentially in the car market. Consumers of type A have inverse demand function
pA(x) = 7 − x,
and consumers of type B have inverse demand function
pB(x) = 5 − x.
There are equal numbers of each type of consumer.  Question: Suppose demand by type As  pA(x) = K − x, for some number K. For what values of K will the monopolist choose to make and sell only high quality cars? What is the deadweight loss in these situations?

Answer: As the quality of cars sold to B types is reduced to zero, the marginal loss on
each of them is 4 (the distance between 5 and 1 on the vertical axis). It would be optimal  to reduce quality this far if the marginal gain on A types was at least this large. This
would happen as long as K ≥ 9. In this situation, B types would lose all of their potential
consumer surplus, so the deadweight loss would be 8 for each one, or 800 in total.

I don't understand the answer.